# How convert rows to columns(SQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do this:
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q17qs.png)

but I actually have this:
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUBIP.png)

this is my sql code:

```
enter code here

SELECT `a`.`itemId` AS itemId, `a`.`donationId` AS `donationId`,
`a`.`typeId` AS `typeId`, `a`.`currencyId` AS `currencyId`,
`a`.memberId AS memberId, `a`.amount_total AS amount_total, a.ref AS
ref, a.ref_bank AS ref_bank, `a`.`hidden` AS `hidden`, a.code AS code,
concat( `b`.`first_name`, ' ', `b`.`last_name` ) AS member_name,
`c`.currencyCode AS currencyCode, `f`.`name` AS `payment_name`,
e.itemEnvelopId,    e.itemId AS itemIdP,    e.accountId,    e.amount,
e.hidden as envelopHidden,  g.NAME, g.new_number 
FROM
ai_donation_items `a` LEFT JOIN ai_church_members `b` ON a.memberId = b.memberId    
LEFT JOIN ai_currency `c` ON a.currencyId = c.currencyId    
LEFT JOIN ai_payment_types `f` ON a.typeId = f.typeId   
LEFT JOIN ai_donation_envelops_item as e on a.itemId = e.itemId 
LEFT JOIN ai_accounts AS g ON e.accountId = g.accountId  
WHERE `a`.`hidden` = 0 AND e.hidden = 0 and a.donationId = 1
```

Comment: You should change

1) The title of this question to reflect what you actually want help with
2) The introductory body of the question, to actually ask the question instead of giving us pictures and forcing us to figure out what you want
3) Reformat your block of code to the correct format

Comment: Also, when using images please don't post links. Embed them into the question so that future users can still see them even if the original source disappears. Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For starters, how do you even expect to get 9 columns when you select 20?  And it doesn't even correspond to your image.